# Angular unit test with TypeScript: TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, typescript

I'm trying to write my first Angular unit test in TypeScript and  I'm getting the follow error and can not find out why. If any one has any idea please let me know.

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.

**test code:**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/karma-jasmine/karma-jasmine.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts" />

describe("FooTest", () => {
    beforeEach(module("app"));

});
```

I'm use [TSD](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd) (TypeScript Definition manager) to manage my TypeScript definitions.

**tsd.json**

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "jquery/jquery.d.ts": {
      "commit": "ef32bff4d15782dbbabf99ecb17ba22119cc2bd2"
    },
    "angularjs/angular.d.ts": {
      "commit": "ef32bff4d15782dbbabf99ecb17ba22119cc2bd2"
    },
    "karma-jasmine/karma-jasmine.d.ts": {
      "commit": "ef32bff4d15782dbbabf99ecb17ba22119cc2bd2"
    },
    "jasmine/jasmine.d.ts": {
      "commit": "ef32bff4d15782dbbabf99ecb17ba22119cc2bd2"
    },
    "angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts": {
      "commit": "ef32bff4d15782dbbabf99ecb17ba22119cc2bd2"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm use IntelliJ IDEA 14

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: just don't run tsc on that spec / mocks / d.ts file? or define `var module: any;`

Comment: @YOU sorry I don't understand what you mean by _just don't run tsc on that spec / mocks / d.ts file?_ that.

Answer (score 16):

Recently Angular team commented the global module in angular-mocks

```
//Use `angular.mock.module` instead of `module`, as `module` conflicts with commonjs.
//declare var module: (...modules: any[]) => any;
```

In order to make your test compile you need to use full namespace, so angular.mock.module

example:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  angular.mock.module('app');
}
```

Comment: I encountered exactly this issue, this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I get the issue where it says that angular doesn't have a property "mock" on it, is there some definition file I'm missing? I have angular-mock that's already on dt, not sure if I need another one

Comment: I have angular-mocks, with the final S, is this what you got or angular-mock?

Answer (score 5):

before:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  module('app');
}
```

after:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  angular.mock.module('app');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

you are using `angular-mocks.d.ts` but I don't see `angular-mocks.ts` anywhere.

`d.ts` files contain only the type definitions, not the actual implementation. So you will need both.

PS: I think that angular-mocks.ts has only the .js version :)